# Bootstrap / SQL: Update multiple selected data to SQL database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, bootstrap-4

From my question above, On a page, there's a select option that can select multiple data at one time. I use bootstrap to do this. Below is the image

[image]

How want to delete all the selected items in the SQL database?

below is my current code.

Item.php

```
<?php

    $smt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ets_tools WHERE status_id = 1 AND borrow_id IS NULL ORDER BY tools_name ASC");
    $smt->execute();
    $results = $smt->fetchAll();

?>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <div class="m-b-1">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="example-search-input" class="col-xs-5 col-form-label"><h3>Item Details<h3></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select data-placeholder="Select your tools" multiple class="select2" name = "tools_id" style="width: 100%;">
              <?php foreach ($results as $row2): ?>
              <option value= <?php echo $row2["tools_id"]; ?>><?php echo $row2["tools_id"]." - ".ucwords($row2["tools_name"]); ?></option>
              <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row" >
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info m-r-xs m-b-xs" name="Submit" style="float:right;">Borrow</button>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can any one know how to solve this.

Comment: What happens when I press the borrow button? A form is submitted? You should have a server side script to handle the form submission and delete the items. Show us your attempt.

Comment: yes... will submit and delete the items

Comment: But you are only showing the code that generates the form. We don't see any code what happens next. I does the borrow button even perform a submit? I don't see a form tag.

Comment: refer my new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337448/php-sql-multiple-delete-data-using-select-option/62337491#62337491